# Limit the number of rows to join to, in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, limit

So I want to join two tables together, but for each row in the first table, I only want to join it to the top 8 matching rows in the other table, ordered by one of the columns in that table.  Any clever syntax I can use, or do I need to get messy with subqueries?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

[How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Section **Select the top N rows from each group**

> This is a slightly harder problem to
>   solve. Finding a single row from each
>   group is easy with SQL’s aggregate
>   functions (MIN(), MAX(), and so on).
>   Finding the first several from each
>   group is not possible with that method
>   because aggregate functions only
>   return a single value. Still, it’s
>   possible to do.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the best solution, but say you're joining on ID, you can use a subquery in your where clause.

```
select from table1 where id in (select top 8 id from table2 order by column1 desc)
```

Comment: The TOP clause is SQL Server only.