# Fetching 10 items each of child table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table categories (`id`, `cat_nam`e) and a table recipes (`id`, `cat_id`, `recipe_text`).

Now I want to write a query, that fetches from each category 10 recipes.

```
SELECT cat_name, recipe_text 
FROM categories c 
JOIN recipes r ON c.id=r.cat_id
```

would fetch ALL recipes, but I want a maximum of 10 recipes per category.

(How) could it be done with a SQL-Query?

Comment: That ain't easy in MySQL.  See [this blog](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) for possible approaches.

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: hope this link may be helpful for you.

[useful link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649596/sql-limit-rows-linked-to-each-joined-row)

Comment: this will help you, please refer here

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637284/mysql-fetch-x-colums-for-each-category-id

Comment: Yap, it's difficult in pure SQL, so we decided to build a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [mySQL Returning the top 5 of each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729406/mysql-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category):

```
SELECT cat_name, recipe_text
FROM
(
   SELECT c.cat_name AS cat_name, r.recipe_text AS recipe_text,
      @r:=case when @g=c.id then @r+1 else 1 end r,
      @g:=c.id
   FROM (select @g:=null,@r:=0) n
   CROSS JOIN categories c
   JOIN recipes r ON c.id = r.cat_id
) X
WHERE r <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL

```
select 
cat_name,
recipe_text 
from categories as c,recipes as r 
where c.id=r.cat_id limit 10
```

Comment: That would just return the first top 10 rows only. The OP is asking for each recipe to be limited to 10 so you could have 100's or rows returned depending on how many categories there are.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code

```
function recipe($cat_id='',$new_ar=array())
{
    if($cat_id!="")
    {
        $new_ar1=array();
        $db="select recipe_text from recipes where cat_id=".$cat_id." order by cat_id limit 10";
        $sq=mysql_query($db);
        while($fe=mysql_fetch_object($sq))
        {
            array_push($new_ar1,$fe->recipe_text);
        }
        return $new_ar1;
    }
    else
    {
        $db="select id,cat_name from categories order by id";
        $sq=mysql_query($db);
        while($fe=mysql_fetch_object($sq))
        {
            array_push($new_ar,$fe->cat_name);

            $new_ar[$fe->id]=array($fe->cat_name);

            array_push($new_ar[$fe->id],recipe($fe->id,$new_ar));
        }
    }

}

recipe();

it will give output like below



Array
(
    [0] => cat 1
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat 1
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => rice
                    [1] => curry
                    [2] => mutton
                    [3] => A recipe
                    [4] => B recipe
                    [5] => C recipe
                    [6] => D recipe
                    [7] => E recipe
                    [8] => F recipe
                    [9] => G recipe
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat 2
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dal
                    [1] => fish
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat 3
            [1] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat 4
            [1] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)

Thanks
Ripa Saha
```

Comment: This looks like php, doesn't it? I'd like to process it directly in the MySQL database. So we went to work with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

this will do for u...

```
     SET @rank = 0;
   SELECT cat_name,recipe_text  FROM (SELECT 
                  id,cat_id AS P,recipe_text,
                  CASE
                  WHEN @rowdata != pid 
                  THEN @rank := 0 & @rowdata := cat_id 
                  ELSE @rank := @rank + 1 
                  END AS rank 
                  FROM
                  recipes  
                  GROUP BY cat_id,
                   id 
                   ) X ,t
                   WHERE X.rank <= 3 AND X.p = t.cat_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

We finally made a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur_id INT;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT id FROM category;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  CREATE TABLE tmp(catname VARCHAR(255), recipeId INT);

  OPEN cur;

  the_loop: LOOP 
    FETCH cur INTO cur_id;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO tmp(catname, recipeId) 
      SELECT catname, recipeId 
      FROM category c LEFT JOIN recipes r ON c.id=r.cat_Id 
      WHERE c.id=cur_id
      LIMIT 0, 10;
  END LOOP;

  SELECT * FROM tmp;
  DROP TABLE tmp;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @num :=0, @cat_id := '';

SELECT recipe_text,cat_name,
       @num := if(@cat_id = cat_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
       @cat_id := cat_id as cat_id
FROM recipes r
JOIN categories c ON c.id = r.cat_id
group by cat_name,recipe_text
having row_number <= 10
```