# Count distinct records from child table for each user in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a competition which counts how many species each user has collected.
this is managed by 3 tables:

1. a parent table called "sub" with collection,each collection is unique, has an id and is associated to a user id.

   ```
   +----+---------+
   | id | user_id |
   +----+---------+
   |  1 |       1 |
   |  2 |      10 |
   |  3 |       1 |
   |  4 |       3 |
   |  5 |       1 |
   |  6 |      10 |
   +----+---------+
   ```
2. the child table called "sub_items" contains multiple unique records of the specs and is related to the parent table by the sub id to id.(each sub can have multiple records of specs)

```
+----+--------+---------+--+
| id | sub_id | spec_id |  |
+----+--------+---------+--+
|  1 |      1 |    1000 |  |
|  2 |      1 |    1003 |  |
|  3 |      1 |    2520 |  |
|  4 |      2 |    7600 |  |
|  5 |      2 |    1000 |  |
|  6 |      3 |      15 |  |
+----+--------+---------+--+
```

3. a user table with associated user_id

```
+--------+-------+--+
| usename | name    |
+---------+-------+--+
|      1 | David    |
|     10 | Ruth     |
|      3 | Rick     |
+--------+-------+--+
```

i need to list the users with the most unique specs collected in a decsending order.
output expected:
 David has a total of 2 unique specs.Ruth has a total of 2 unique specs.

```
+--------+---------+
| id     | total   |
+----+-------------+
|  David |    2    |
|  Ruth  |    2    |
|  Rick  |    2    |
+----+-------------+
```

so far i have this,it produces a result. but its not accurate, it counts the total records.
im probably missing a DISTINCT somewhere in the sub-query.

```
SELECT s.id, s.user_id,u.name, sum(t.count) as total
FROM sub s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, sub_id, count(id) as count FROM sub_items GROUP BY sub_id
 ) t ON t.sub_id = s.id
 LEFT JOIN user u ON u.username = s.user_id
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY total DESC
```

i have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995651/get-n-number-of-records-from-child-table-for-each-parent-record-in-a-mysql-view) solution, but it doesn't consider the unique aspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first have to get the max "score" for all the users like:

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT si.id) as total
    FROM sub INNER JOIN sub_items si ON sub.id = su.sub_id
    GROUP BY sub.user_id
    ORDER BY total DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Then you can use that to restrict your query to users that share that max score:

```
SELECT u.name, count(DISTINCT si.id) as total
FROM
    user u
    INNER JOIN sub ON u.usename = sub.user_id
    INNER JOIN sub_items si ON sub.id = su.sub_id
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING total =
    (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT si.id) as total
        FROM sub INNER JOIN sub_items si ON sub.id = su.sub_id
        GROUP BY sub.user_id
        ORDER BY total DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: thanks ! im not sure if you understood what i needed, could figure out what you meant by "Max score". what i wanted it the total score ordered from highest to lowest.

Comment: In that case you can just remove that `HAVING` clause and everything add it and substitute with `ORDER BY total desc`. There is no need for a subquery here.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, i have to add the

```
COUNT(distinct spec_id)
```

to the sub-query

```
SELECT s.id, s.user_id,u.name, sum(t.count) as total
FROM sub s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sub_id, COUNT(distinct spec_id) as count FROM sub_items group by sub_id
 ) t ON t.sub_id = s.id
 LEFT JOIN user u ON u.username = s.user_id
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY total DESC
```